# R max function ignore NA

Tags: r, max

I have below working code. When i replicate same things on a different data set i get errors :(

```
#max by values
df <- data.frame(age=c(5,NA,9), marks=c(1,2,7), story=c(2,9,NA))
df

df$colMax <- apply(df[,1:3], 1, function(x) max(x[x != 9],na.rm=TRUE))
df
```

I tried to do the same on a bigger data and I am getting warnings, why?

```
maindata$max_pc_age <- apply(maindata[,c(paste("Q2",1:18,sep="_"))], 1, function(x) max(x[x != 9],na.rm=TRUE))


50: In max(x[x != 9], na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

in order to understand the problem better I made changes as below, but still getting warnings

```
maindata$max_pc_age <- apply(maindata[,c(paste("Q2",1:18,sep="_"))], 1, function(x) max(x,na.rm=TRUE))
1: In max(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: Can you figure out the problem from the result of `max(numeric(0))`, or do you need more explanation?

Comment: still need help ...I tried class( numeric(0)) and it returned numeric..shouldnt max function work on it?

Comment: It _is_ working. If a vector has no elements in it, what is the maximum value? You're asking for the max of values that _are not 9 and are not NA_. Apparently sometimes that leaves nothing left.

Comment: @joran: the maximum of nothing is obvious `-Inf`.

Comment: i tried max(maindata[1,c(paste("Q2",1:18,sep="_"))],na.rm=TRUE) and it returned a value

Comment: got it, how should i change my code if some of the rows contain either 9 or NA?

Comment: Depends on what you think is "correct". You aren't getting an error, just a warning. If you think `-Inf` doesn't make sense for those cases, change them to `NA` after the fact. Or omit those rows entirely.

Comment: I would like max function to return "missing" when a row contain either 9 or NA

Comment: You can't mix character and numeric in a vector. `NA` means "missing" in R. Just change the `-Inf`'s to `NA`. Or just write a longer function with an `if` clause that checks that case first.

Comment: I tried maindata$max_pc_age[maindata$max_pc_age==-Inf]<- "NA"  and it solves my problem. do you see any problem with this line of a code?

Comment: Yes, a big one. Your whole vector will be characters not numbers.

Comment: Got it...but i can work with characters...If you post your comments below I will mark that as accepted answer...thanks for educating me!

Answer (score 19):

It seems that the problem has been pointed out in the comments already. Since some vectors contain only `NA`s, `-Inf` is reported, which I take from the comments you don't like. In this answer I would like to point out one possible way to tackle the issue, namely to built in a control statement (instead of overwritting `-Inf` after the fact, which is equally valid). For instance,

```
 my.max <- function(x) ifelse( !all(is.na(x)), max(x, na.rm=T), NA)
```

does this trick. If every (`all`) element in `x` is `NA`, then `NA` is returned, and the `max` otherwise. If you want any other value returned, just exchange `NA` for that value. You can also built this easily into your `apply`-function. E.g.

```
 maindata$max_pc_age <- apply(maindata[,c(paste("Q2",1:18,sep="_"))], 1, my.max)
```

I am still sometimes confused by R's `NA` and empty set treatment. Statements like  `test <- NA; test==NA` will give `NA` as a result (instead of `TRUE`, as returned by `is.na(test)`), which is sometimes rationalized by saying that since the value is missing, how could you know that these two missing values are identical? In this case, however, `max` returns `-Inf` since it is given an empty set, which I think is not at all obvious. My experience is though that if strange and unexpected results pop up, `NA`s or empty sets are often involved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hablar::max_` which returns `NA` if all values are `NA`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) hablar::max_(x[x!=9]))
#[1]  5 NA  7
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(age = c(5, NA, 9), marks = c(-5, NA, 7), story = c(2, 
9, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df
#  age marks story
#1   5    -5     2
#2  NA    NA     9
#3   9     7    NA
```

Comment: Why does `hablar::max_(1, NA)` return an error? Even `hablar::max_(1, NA, ignore_na = TRUE)` returns this error: `Error in hablar::max_(1, NA, ignore_na = TRUE) : unused argument (NA)`

Answer (score 1):

In cases like below:

```
df[2,2] <- NA
df[1,2] <- -5

apply(df, 1, function(x) max(x[x != 9],na.rm=TRUE))
#[1]    5 -Inf    7
#Warning message:
#In max(x[x != 9], na.rm = TRUE) :
#  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

You could do:

```
df1 <- df  
minVal <- min(df1[!is.na(df1)])-1

df1[is.na(df1)|df1==9] <- minVal
val <- do.call(`pmax`, df1)
val[val==minVal] <- NA
val
#[1]  5 NA  7
```

Comment: +1 for pmax/pmin, although better methods could be developed when only one unlabeled argument is passed, precluding all this `do.call` business. You can overload it to make `na.rm=T` the default, or you can say, `do.call(pmax, c(df1, list(na.rm=T))`.