# Extract maximum number from a text string

Tags: r, string, max

I want to extract the highest numeric value from each string considering that sometimes that string will be an NA, which will be copied as NA.

I've tried the following solution:

```
df2$val = sapply(strsplit(df2$NomNivelComplej , '\\D+'), function(x) max(as.numeric(x)))
```

But all I get is NA

Data

```
df2 = structure(list(IdCx = c(47111L, 47111L, 47111L, 47111L, 47108L, 
47108L, 47107L, 47107L, 47106L, 47106L), NomNivelComplej = c("De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.", 
NA, "De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.", "De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.", "De 91 Hasta 100 U.V.R.", 
"De 131 Hasta 150 U.V.R.", "De 31 Hasta 40 U.V.R.", "De 71 Hasta 80 U.V.R.", 
"De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.", "De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please include the expected output in your question?

Comment: Adding `na.rm=T` to your `max` function will certainly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `na.rm = T` to your `max` function, and then replace infinite values with `NA`.

```r
df2$val <- sapply(strsplit(df2$NomNivelComplej , '\\D+'), function(x) max(as.integer(x), na.rm = T))
df2$val <- replace(df2$val, is.infinite(df2$val), NA)
```

You could also use a built-in function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24520992/13460602)).

```r
mymax <- function(x) ifelse( !all(is.na(x)), max(x, na.rm=T), NA)
df2$val <- sapply(strsplit(df2$NomNivelComplej , '\\D+'), function(x) mymax(as.integer(x)))
```

Output:

```r
# > df2
#     IdCx         NomNivelComplej val
# 1  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
# 2  47111                    <NA>  NA
# 3  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
# 4  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
# 5  47108  De 91 Hasta 100 U.V.R. 100
# 6  47108 De 131 Hasta 150 U.V.R. 150
# 7  47107   De 31 Hasta 40 U.V.R.  40
# 8  47107   De 71 Hasta 80 U.V.R.  80
# 9  47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
# 10 47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
```

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` and `stringr` solution that doesn't assume anything about where the number is inside the string:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
get_max = function(x) {
    vals = unlist(str_split(x, "\\D"))
    max(as.numeric(vals[vals != ""]))
}

df2 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(max_val = get_max(NomNivelComplej))
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Rowwise: 
    IdCx NomNivelComplej         max_val
   <int> <chr>                     <dbl>
 1 47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.     130
 2 47111 NA                           NA
 3 47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.     130
 4 47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.     130
 5 47108 De 91 Hasta 100 U.V.R.      100
 6 47108 De 131 Hasta 150 U.V.R.     150
 7 47107 De 31 Hasta 40 U.V.R.        40
 8 47107 De 71 Hasta 80 U.V.R.        80
 9 47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.     130
10 47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.     130
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R`

```
df2$Max <-  do.call(pmax, read.csv(text = trimws(gsub("\\D+", ",", 
     df2$NomNivelComplej), whitespace = ","), header = FALSE))
```

-output

```
> df2
    IdCx         NomNivelComplej Max
1  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
2  47111                    <NA>  NA
3  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
4  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
5  47108  De 91 Hasta 100 U.V.R. 100
6  47108 De 131 Hasta 150 U.V.R. 150
7  47107   De 31 Hasta 40 U.V.R.  40
8  47107   De 71 Hasta 80 U.V.R.  80
9  47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
10 47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt all `` `length<-` ``'s to `3`, calculate the `colMaxs` (using `matrixStats` package) and `replace` if `is.infinite` with `NA`.

```
df2$val <- df2$NomNivelComplej  |>
  strsplit('\\D+') |>
  sapply(`length<-`, 3) |>
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) |>
  matrixStats::colMaxs(na.rm=TRUE) |>
  (\(.) replace(., is.infinite(.), NA))()
df2
#     IdCx         NomNivelComplej val
# 1  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
# 2  47111                    <NA>  NA
# 3  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
# 4  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
# 5  47108  De 91 Hasta 100 U.V.R. 100
# 6  47108 De 131 Hasta 150 U.V.R. 150
# 7  47107   De 31 Hasta 40 U.V.R.  40
# 8  47107   De 71 Hasta 80 U.V.R.  80
# 9  47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
# 10 47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R. 130
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used

---

*Data:*

```
df2 <- structure(list(IdCx = c(47111L, 47111L, 47111L, 47111L, 47108L, 
47108L, 47107L, 47107L, 47106L, 47106L), NomNivelComplej = c("De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.", 
NA, "De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.", "De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.", "De 91 Hasta 100 U.V.R.", 
"De 131 Hasta 150 U.V.R.", "De 31 Hasta 40 U.V.R.", "De 71 Hasta 80 U.V.R.", 
"De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.", "De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows:

```
temp <- c()
for (i in df2$NomNivelComplej) {
  j <- max(as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(i, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", i)))), na.rm = T)
  temp <- c(temp, j)
}

df2 <- cbind(df2, temp)
```

Output:

```
    IdCx         NomNivelComplej temp
1  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
2  47111                    <NA> -Inf
3  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
4  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
5  47108  De 91 Hasta 100 U.V.R.  100
6  47108 De 131 Hasta 150 U.V.R.  150
7  47107   De 31 Hasta 40 U.V.R.   40
8  47107   De 71 Hasta 80 U.V.R.   80
9  47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
10 47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
```

Note: It returns `-Inf` in the case of `NA`. But, you can always take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can capitalize on the fact that the string-highest value always follows "Hasta ":

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
  mutate(max = str_extract(NomNivelComplej, "(?<=Hasta )\\d+"))
    IdCx         NomNivelComplej  max
1  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
2  47111                    <NA> <NA>
3  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
4  47111 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
5  47108  De 91 Hasta 100 U.V.R.  100
6  47108 De 131 Hasta 150 U.V.R.  150
7  47107   De 31 Hasta 40 U.V.R.   40
8  47107   De 71 Hasta 80 U.V.R.   80
9  47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
10 47106 De 111 Hasta 130 U.V.R.  130
```

In `base R`:

```
library(stringr)
df2$max <- str_extract(df2$NomNivelComplej, "(?<=Hasta )\\d+")
```